# Lost access to application when user was deleted

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We deleted an "unused" user in our Azure AD. Deleting both the MS account as well as removing him from the AD. Now, a few days into the 60 day deletion process (of the MS account) we realize he might have been the creator of an AD application that we can now no longer find anywhere. My guess it is was a "private" application? But somehow still in AD? Not sure exactly.

We reopened the MS account and created the user again in the AD (as a global admin), but the application is no-where to be found. If we try to access the application via a direct link we have lying around, we see a 403 No Access page, and an error notification in the notification center that suggests there's a permission issue but the user is a global admin again:

> Additional information from the call to get a token: Extension:
> Microsoft_AAD_IAM Resource: identity.diagnostics Details: AADSTS50020:
> User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider 'live.com' does
> not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the
> application 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'(ADIbizaUX) in that tenant. The account
> needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out
> and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user
> account. Trace ID: xxxxxxxx Correlation xxxxxxx Timestamp: 2020-06-25
> 14:44:18Z

We've also tried logging in with multiple other global admins but no-one can access that page or find the application using the id it has. Is there something to be done maybe using Powershell?

Actually, as I recall, it might have been an application listed for this user under 'App registrations' -> 'Applications from personal account'. But that tab is no longer available after deleting and reopening the user :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize it was possible to restore a deleted Azure AD user (for 30 days). Once I restored the deleted AD user instead of creating the user again, the app appeared again in the user's 'Applications from personal account' under 'App registrations'.

I'd still love to move the app to the Azure AD proper, but from an earlier SO question I was told that's not possible. I guess we'll either keep this old account or create the app again (and have all our users reauthorize).

Answer (score 0):

As per the New changes made in the Azure portal app registration

> In the new experience, if your personal Microsoft account is also in
> an Azure AD tenant, you will see three tabs--all applications in the
> tenant, owned applications in the tenant as well as applications from
> your personal account. So, if you believe that apps registered with
> your personal Microsoft account are missing, check the Applications
> from your personal account tab.

> When you sign in using personal Microsoft accounts(e.g. Outlook, Live,
> Xbox, etc.) with an Azure AD email address, we found out that when you
> go to the Azure portal from the old experience, it signs you into a
> different account with the same email in your Azure AD tenant. If you
> still believe your applications are missing, sign out and sign in with
> the right account.

> The new app list shows applications that were registered through the
> legacy app registrations experience in the Azure portal (apps that
> sign in Azure AD accounts only) as well as apps registered though the
> Application registration portal (apps that sign in both Azure AD and
> personal Microsoft accounts).

If you know the application ID you can restore using [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/restore-azureaddeletedapplication?view=azureadps-2.0)

The error is due to using the v1 endpoint url. You need to use V2 endpoints in order to allow access from personal microsoft accounts.

Use this endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

Please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-registration-portal-training-guide)

Comment: Thanks. Before I deleted the MS user and AD user of the email account that owned the application, there was this personal applications area where the application was in.

That area has not come back when reopening the MS user or creating a new AD user with the same email. The application isn't actually "deleted" though, as it's still live and used for OAuth2 - we just can't find it anywhere to access it :) But of course we do have the id.